# Using onClick to open a new android activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've seen a few other questions similar to this, but I still cant seem to get an answer.

What I would ideally like is to use the intent method as shown below to switch to another activity.

Here is my MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void sendCalc (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and this is my second activity:
{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
}
```

and here is my xml file for the button.

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/createCalc"
        android:onClick="sendCalc"
        android:elevation="2dp" />
```

Also, I have added the second activity in the manifest file.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the name of second activity? Is `MainActivity` the second activity which you want to start? `Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);`

Comment: @ShobhitPuri the second activity is called calculation

Comment: So instead of MaijActivity.class use the second activity name

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give you an example of one of my app's code to change to the next activity

```
NextPage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    NextPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

You put this over the:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: sorry, this might be stupid , but what does `NextPage` stand for

Comment: I just get a whole lot of errors

Comment: You need to have a button to do a OnClick intent "NextPage" is the Button name in the MainActivity.class

Comment: You need to create another activity so it can move to there else you wont get anything from this code

Comment: I have another activity its called calculation. here is it in full:

Comment: `package com.example.muaaz.emscalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class calculation extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
` @Marroquino

Comment: Can you send me a snapshot of your second activity? with the android studio project browser?

Comment: I get an error saying that it needs something like a `public void` or something (your given code). invalid method type

Comment: are you putting the code i gave you in the first or second activity?

Comment: first @Marroquino

Comment: how u do snapshot (send)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I have now managed to get the answer, it was a stupid mistake of mine setting the layout for the second activity. All Appreciated @Marroquino

Comment: No problem you could show your appreciation accepting my answer